# a2enmod not working on debian (buster)

Tags: debian

Running a2enmod gives:

`bash: a2enmod: command not found`

I've hunted high and low and can't find any answers. Is there something I need to do/install?

Comment: Have you installed apache2?

Comment: You need to run the command as root. You can do this with `sudo a2enmod ...`

Comment: I've been running the command as root and I have installed apache2.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Also if you used to open your root session with "su", then after upgrading to buster make sure to use "su -" instead, otherwise some commands won't be available (including a2enmod).

Comment: This fixed it, nice one!

Comment: This worked for me as well.  Can you explain why this fixes the issue? Thank you.

Comment: @hendr1x In Debian 10 you can `su` to root but if you want the most powerful features you have to go up a level by running `su -` instead. I hope that helps.

Comment: BTW This change is documented in https://wiki.debian.org/NewInBuster

Answer (score 4):

It's a PATH variable bug.

Try this:

```
apt-get install mlocate
updatedb
locate a2enmod
```

the output is:

```
/usr/sbin/a2enmod
```

then

```
 grep PATH /etc/profile


PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin"
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
Export PATH
```

As you can see, /usr/sbin in not in root $PATH

So, edit the first line to

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin"
```

And then

```
# . /etc/profile
```

And then you are OK.

Comment: Actually `/usr/sbin` is the last entry in the first line.

Comment: the step to _"edit the first line to"_ matches the first line. what is the difference?

Comment: also the _"As you can see, `/usr/sbin` is not in root $PATH"_ line doesn't make sense as it is in the $PATH, even in your example.

Comment: However, I will give you a vote up because running `. /etc/profile` did fix my problem

Comment: @Oxymoron thankyou . /etc/profile solve my prob. too

Answer (score 1):

You need to have installed apache2

> sudo apt install apache2

and sudo a2enmod file

you can also do a symbolic link:

ln -s /rute/ /rute2/

Comment: He can't create a symbolic link if he's not root. And the syntax would be `cd /etc/apache2/mods-enabled; ln -s ../mods-available/foo`

Comment: I've read that I shouldn't be doing it that way and that I should be using the a2* functions instead which is why I'm trying not to revert to doing that.

Answer (score 0):

just put the PATH in root's ~/.bashrc file